# js - function to display a different line of text for each selection

Tags: javascript, html, output, display

I'm new to js and need a bit of help with my homework assignment.
I created a list of numbers from 1 to 12 and I need the browser to display a different output on each selection.
So if I pick number 1 and click on the button, it should call a function to check the value of that number and display a corresponding message below....

I don't really know a lot about js or programming in general for that matter. I know what I tried is probably all wrong but I hope that I at least got the idea of what i need across.

```
<head>
<script>
myFunction();
function myFunction() {
var track = document.getElementById("Selection");
if (track = 1) {
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "1111"
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
Select A Track For More Information:
<select id="Selection">
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
<option>4</option>
<option>5</option>
<option>6</option>
<option>7</option>
<option>8</option>
<option>9</option>
<option>10</option>
<option>11</option>
<option>12</option>
</select>
<br><br>
<input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" 
value="Click Here For More Information">
</form>
<p id="demo"></p>
</body>
```

I get no output

Comment: Best to call functions *after* you define them, make sure your DOM loads *before* your script runs, and use `==` for comparison, *not* `=`. That should solve all your problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you didn't get value of `select` , also you need to use `==` operator to compare . i.e :

```js
//onload calling function
myFunction();
function myFunction() {
//getting value of select
var track = document.getElementById("Selection").value;
//if select value is 1
if (track ==1) {
//print message
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "1 Your message";
}else if (track ==2) {
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "2 Your message";
}
else if (track ==3) {
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "3 Your message";
}
else if (track ==4) {
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = " 4 Your message";
}else{
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = " Your message";
}
}
```

```html
<body>
Select A Track For More Information:
<select id="Selection">
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
<option>4</option>
<option>5</option>
<option>6</option>
<option>7</option>
<option>8</option>
<option>9</option>
<option>10</option>
<option>11</option>
<option>12</option>
</select>
<br><br>
<input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" 
value="Click Here For More Information">

<p id="demo"></p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript you should use `===` operator to compare.
[Comparison Operators](https://i.stack.imgur.com/czMJD.png)
Link to [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp)

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION:**

'if' condition should be of === or !== operator. And a minor change has been made for you to understand better.

**CODE SNIPPET:**

```html
<body>
  Select A Track For More Information:
  <select id="Selection">
    <option selected>0</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
    <option>6</option>
    <option>7</option>
    <option>8</option>
    <option>9</option>
    <option>10</option>
    <option>11</option>
    <option>12</option>
  </select>
  <br><br>
  <input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" 
  value="Click Here For More Information">
  <p id="demo"></p>
  
  <script>
  function myFunction() {
     var track = document.getElementById("Selection");
     // checks if value is non-zero
     if (track.value && track.value !== "0") {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = track.value + " is the chosen value!";
     } else {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Selected value is not supported!";
     }
   }
   
   myFunction();
  </script>
</body>
```